# Find in which columns lies the text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

Thanks for reading this!

Lets say we have 2 columns in this workbook called "Data":

```
| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Joshua    | Noah          |
| Daniel   | Joshua         |
```

In another workbook, I want the user to input some random name in a cell.

Below that cell, I want to be able to show him/her, in which column that name lies. E.g. if he types "Joshua", I want to be shown below:

```
||
|--|
|Column A|
|Column B|
```

I prefer using a formula, instead of VBA, as it would mess with my not-so-experienced end-user!

Notes: See below my attempt if you find it useful:

(1) I tried that using a nested IF + FILTER functions inside, but the IF returns only the first TRUE column, like this:

```
| |
|------|
| Column A |
| Column A |
```

Here is my actual formula, where I'm referring to split ranges in sheet "6", where I have 4 columns:

```
IF(NOT(ISERROR(FILTER('6'!B4#,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$4,'6'!B4#))))),'6'!$B$1,
IF(NOT(ISERROR(FILTER('6'!D4#,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$4,'6'!D4#))))),'6'!$D$1,
IF(NOT(ISERROR(FILTER('6'!F4#,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$4,'6'!F4#))))),'6'!$F$1,
IF(NOT(ISERROR(FILTER('6'!H4#,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$4,'6'!H4#))))),'6'!$H$1,""))))
```

Comment: If you're ok with blanks, a VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP may be what you're after.  Take a look at those two functions and think about using one for each column of names in the fields below your "Entry" field.  But you also must consider what happens if a column has the same name multiple times (or is this possible) [MSFT DOCS - VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=FILTER(TRANSPOSE(A1:B1),MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(A2:B3)=D1),SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:B3),,,0)),"")
```

Comment: I like this approach it is 2 functions I never use myself. But when I try your solution for Daniel and Noah I get the wrong column name.

Comment: @W_O_L_F. Correct, great spot. Didn't think too much about it but I needed to transpose the data first.

Comment: This works neatly! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the column numbers with this formula (original data on worksheet "10")

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,1/('10'!A:D="Joshua")*COLUMN('10'!A:D),SEQUENCE(COUNTIF('10'!A:D,"Joshua")))
```

Although I suggest reducing the range references from full columns to something shorter to reduce calculation times.

With Office 365, you can convert the column number to the letter with this:

```
=LET(col,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/('10'!A:D="Joshua")*COLUMN('10'!A:D),SEQUENCE(COUNTIF('10'!A:D,"Joshua"))),
          adr,ADDRESS(1,col,2),
         "Column " & LEFT(adr,FIND("$",adr)-1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your last formula fits my question almost 100%. I just changed the formula to show Column Header Names instead of column letters. So from this: "Column " & LEFT(adr,FIND("$",adr)-1))  to this IF(LEFT(adr,FIND("$",adr)-1)="H","Column H name",IF(LEFT(adr,FIND("$",adr)-1)="J","Column J name","")))